# Weird CoD AW Gold Edition problem PC

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

Today something very weird happened to me. I played a game of FFA (on a non-DLC map) and I got a supply drop. When I opened it, there was an AE4 inside (I don't know which variant).

I wanted to equip it in a class, but when I chose it, the game opened the Steam library. It showed the page for the *Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare Gold Edition*, but it said that it was already in my library.

I scrolled down to the text:

> Gold Edition now available.
>
> The CoD AW Gold Edition includes the full game PLUS Havoc ..

- My CoD AW shortcut's target is `steam://rungameid/209650`
- The URL of CoD AW Gold in Steam library is `http://store.steampowered.com/app/209650`

Also, when I play a private match with only bots, some of them wield the AE4.

I bought the game on DVDs and I don't have the Havoc DLC. What is going on?

---

**EDIT**: I went through the game files and now I'm even more confused. I found files named:

```
eng_patch_common_CORE_mp.ff
eng_patch_mp_URBAN.ff
eng_patch_mp_ZOMBIE_LAB.ff
```

Core and Urban are MP maps in Havoc DLC, and I assume that zombie_lab is [Outbreak](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Outbreak) because it's an Atlas research lab.

There are also dozens of other Exo Zombies related files. The bots can wield the AE4 because there are files related to dlcgun1 which is [AE4](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/AE4).

My Info:

- **Location:** Croatia
- **System:** Windows 7 x64 Professional alongside OS X on a late 2014 MacBook Pro
- **Steam name:** progamer3141

Comment: The link to the Gold edition is because the normal game isn't available in the steam store anymore. I think whats going on is a kind of advertising, they want you to buy the havoc dlc.

Comment: Yes, but how did the files for the AE4 (dlcgun1) end up among files for other weapons?

Comment: I wouldn't care about any  gamefiles. Most of the times the DLC's are already within the game and if you buy it, they just unlock it. I bet if you would buy the havoc dlc you wouldn't download anything or just a little "unlock file" with a size of a few kb's

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug which is not yet fixed. [Here's a reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/CodAW/comments/2twdgq/ae4_not_unlocking/) (2 month old) where people discuss exactly your problem. If you read a few reviews on the [Havoc-Dlc Steampage](http://store.steampowered.com/app/318791/) you'll see that there're still a lot of people who got the same bug. For now all you can do is to wait for a patch that fix this problem, I wasn't able to find any workaround.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I didn't buy the Havoc DLC. On the reddit page they have the Havoc DLC pack. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the game in your library, scroll down. There will be DLCs on the right, with checkboxes next to the DLC names.

Tick the boxes and it will be downloaded automatically.

Comment: There aren't any boxes when I click DLC on the right. Just names of DLC and an Add to cart button for each DLC. When I click Havoc DLC, it opens up a page where's a video about the DLC, Add to cart button, About, system requirements and comments.